# Woocommerce Storefront. Добавить несколько цен в товар

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-плагины

В товаре предусмотрено 3 цены, в зависимости от размера. Возле каждой цены кнопка "в корзину". Каким способом можно добавить еще несколько вариаций с работающими кнопками? Создание дубликата в `_regular_price` ничего не дало (это ожидаемо, но попробовать стоило).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Несколько цен в зависимости от размера реализовуется через аттрибуты товара.
https://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/woocommerce-edu/how-to-use-product-attributes-in-woocommerce

Comment: а как их вывести в карточках товара на странице категорий, а не самой странице товара? Да и получается селект на странице товара, а мне нужен не селект, а примерно так:

100$ 1x   В КОРЗИНУ,
200$ 2x   В КОРЗИНУ,
300$ 3x   В КОРЗИНУ